# Issues on creating a while loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I need to run a while loop that prints every one of it's results, but can't get it to work properly. Here's what i have achieved:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    float fahrenheit;
    int celsius;

    printf("Table of calsius degrees in fahrenheit 1-100:");
    celsius=0;
    fahrenheit=32;
    while (0 < celsius < 100)
    {
        celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit-32);

        fahrenheit = ((9.0 / 5.0) * celsius )+ 32;

        printf ("%f , %f\n", celsius,fahrenheit);
        celsius ++;
    }
    if (celsius>=101){
        printf("Jobs done");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. The goal was for it to print every value fahrenheit and celsius from 1 to 100.

Comment: `while (0 < celsius < 100)` this is not what you think it is. You mean `while(celsius > 0 && celsius < 100)`

Comment: What do you mean by work properly? It is outputting an error? Is it not outputting the correct results?

Comment: Turn on full warnings, you should see something like `comparison of constant 100 with boolean expression is always true`

Comment: Also note: 1) that since you initialise your variable `Celsius` as 0, you won't even enter the loop anyway. 2) since you recalculate `celsius` each time, it may happen that you stop looping since you will lose precision and end up not rounding up, and will end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Even if that was correct syntax, you'd never get into the loop. You set `celsius` to `0`, so `0 < celsius < 100` will be false the first time.

Comment: What you want is: `for (int celsius = 0; celsius < 100; ++celsius) {` instead of that really bizarre `while` loop with tons of internal modifications and re-assignments from °F->°C and °C->°F.

Comment: You also have a logic problem. You're incrementing `celsius`, but then immediately resetting it from `fahrenheit`.

Comment: If you do ``int celsius``` but use ```%f``` print modifier, you'll get weird results, so use ```%i```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the condition like

```
while ( celsius++ < 100)
```

and remove these statements from the loop

```
celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit-32);
```

and

```
celsius ++;
```

And after the loop it is enough to write

```
printf("Jobs done");
```

without the if statement.

Comment: Not sure why `Celsius` is capitalized there.

Comment: @tadman I'm guessing an autocorrect.

Comment: Fixed, so that's good.